# aws bucket policy to allow Facebook to show open graph images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, facebook-opengraph

I can't seem to get Facebook to have access to the resources I put in my open graph tags in my bucket policy.

This is my current policy, meant to prevent hotlinking but allow Facebook (and ideally other social networks) to access my images (and other resources)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "idance and social only",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Explicitly only allow only from specific referer.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::common-resources-idance-net/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://example.com/*",
                        "*facebook*",
                        "*twitter*",
                        "*google*"
                    ],

                    "aws:UserAgent": [
                        "*facebook*",
                        "*twitter*",
                        "*google*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.idance.net%2Fen%2Flessons%2F2850-complete-bhangra-dance-routine-to-hass-hogia-online-bhangra-dance-lesson-with-honey-kalaria) link saying that (and presumably why) the scraping for the resources fails.

The error for the inaccessible image is:

```
could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond.
```

But the image is not large and S3 is not slow. So I imagine that this is a bucket policy issue.

I'm not sure what I'm missing but can anyone shed some light on what I might change to make this work?

Update: I removed the policy entirely, and it seems to not had any effect. Perhaps some special header needs to be sent to Facebook when scraping?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html  :  `Make sure the browsers you use include the http referer header in the request.`   This policy is mean for user browser page.

Comment: The seemingly obvious thing to try is to first be sure it works as expected with an allow-all policy, then allow based on only the user agent test or only the referer test and see which one is not working as expected, remembering that policy changes may take a few seconds to become active.